# C programming fscanf segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf

I am trying to read from a file that has comma seperated values like so (5th field should only have r/b/n and 6th field is y/n:

```
531,A,10,10,b,n,96.00,100.00
531,B,15,15,b,n,144.00,0.00
531,C,20,20,b,n,192.00,0.00
533,A,11,11,r,n,123.20,100.00
533,B,22,22,r,n,246.40,0.00
```

I have the following fscanf code block to parse the file by line and store values in an array which I alter/output later.

```
while(fscanf(data, "%4[0-9],%[A-Z],%3[0-9],%3[0-9],[prb],[yn],%d,%d\n", &house[i], room[i], &length[i], &width[i], paintcode[i], ceilingcode[i], &cost[i], &setupcost[i]) != EOF) {
   printf("%d,%c,%d,%d,%c,%c,%.2lf,%.2lf\n", &house[i], room[i], &length[i], &width[i], paintcode[i], ceilingcode[i], &cost[i], &setupcost[i]);
   i++;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a Segmentation fault and it occurs at this line. I have altered and tested it for about an hour and I am pretty sure I have it right, unless I am missing something. Any help would be appreciated, the full main function is pasted below.

```
main() {
   FILE *data;
   int house[200];
   char room[200];
   int length[200];
   int width[200];
   char paintcode[200];
   char ceilingcode[200];
   double cost[200];
   double setupcost[200];
   char line;
   int MAX_BUFF = 200;
   char x[200];
   double price[100];
   int i = 0, num_records = 0;

   data = fopen("quotes.data","r");
   if(data == NULL){
      printf("Error: file can't be open..\n");
   } else {
      while(fscanf(data, "%4[0-9],%[A-Z],%3[0-9],%3[0-9],[prb],[yn],%d,%d\n", &house[i], room[i], &length[i], &width[i], paintcode[i], ceilingcode[i], &cost[i], &setupcost[i]) != EOF) {
         printf("%d,%c,%d,%d,%c,%c,%.2lf,%.2lf\n", &house[i], room[i], &length[i], &width[i], paintcode[i], ceilingcode[i], &cost[i], &setupcost[i]);
         i++;
      }
      fclose(data);
```

Comment: Please write in at least C89 and preferably C99 - which in context means specifying a return type (`int` for `main()`) and the parameter list, leading to `int main(void)`.

Comment: Note that your loop places the first string for room at offset 0 in the string; the second string starts at offset 1 in the room array.  Your printing is (more or less) consistent with that, so it will work, but you are gradually leaving yourself less and less space to store the strings.  Read 200 entries and you're scribbling all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few issues here.

For a start, the `scanf` family will only return `EOF` if reading failed without getting *any* input values. If you successfully get *some but not all,* you will get a count of the number successfully scanned (including the case where you got them all).

You also need to pass the *address* of the variables you want to populate, which you haven't done for all of them.

In addition, a format specifier like `%4[0-9]` will read *characters,* not a single integer so it would require a character buffer, not an address of an integer as you have. If you want an integer populated, you need to use something like `%4d`.

On the `%[A-Z]` front, these actually create a null-terminated string so you need to allow space for that.

Also ensure you can read the the *floating point* values at the end of the line rather than integers, and you're missing some `%` format characters.

And lastly, `printf` requires addresses only for string arguments.

The following program shows this in action in simplified form (no arrays) with your input file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    FILE *data;
    char room[2], paintcode[2], ceilingcode[2];
    int house, length, width;
    double cost, setupcost;

    data = fopen("quotes.data","r");
    if (data == NULL) {
        printf("Error: file can't be opened.\n");
    } else {
        while (fscanf (data, "%4d,%[A-Z],%3d,%3d,%[prb],%[yn],%lf,%lf\n",
            &house, room, &length, &width, paintcode, ceilingcode, &cost,
            &setupcost) == 8)
        {
            printf ("%d,%c,%d,%d,%c,%c,%.2lf,%.2lf\n",
                house, *room, length, width, *paintcode, *ceilingcode,
                cost, setupcost);
        }
    }
    fclose(data);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the way you worded explained it perfectly and its working beautifully now, now to just parse the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take address (as in `&house[i]`) only when you pass arguments to `fscanf`. Integer and single-character arguments of `fprintf` are passed by value:

```
printf("%d,%c,%d,%d,%c,%c,%.2lf,%.2lf\n", house[i], room[i], length[i], width[i], paintcode[i], ceilingcode[i], cost[i], setupcost[i]);
```

Calls to `fscanf`, on the other hand, require pointers. Since you are scanning single-characters as characters, not as strings, you should be passing an address of room, paintcode, etc.

Comment: Thanks, for the help. It was giving me some errors, printing out the results of the fscanf and the way you explained it made it click.

Answer (score 0):

Check the return value of scanf properly

```
RETURN VALUE
   These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and 
   assigned,  which  can  be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event
   of an early matching failure.
```